# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' is most specific for these arguments

Tags: vb.net

This is the code:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "Total profil for all time" Then

        Dim TA As New CPDBTableAdapters.TotalProfilForAllTimeTableAdapter
        Dim TmpDS As New CPDB
        TA.Fill(TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime)


        'obriši prošli DS
        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

        'dodaj novi DS
        Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("", TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime)
        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)
        RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "change_password.report1.rdlc"
        RV.RefreshReport()


    End If
```

Problem is here:

```
Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("", 
    TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime)
```

Error message:
overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new'is most specific for these arguments.

Comment: What is the type of `TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime`?

Comment: TotalProfilForAllTime is tableadapter, TmpDs. is (Dim TmpDS As New CPDB)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime, cast the second argument passed to the constructor:

```
Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("", CType(TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime, DataTable))
```

or:

```
Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("", CType(TmpDS.TotalProfilForAllTime, IEnumerable))
```

etc.

VB can't clearly pick the best constructor overload, so you have to provide some help to the compiler. See this link for the possible 2nd argument types expected.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.reportdatasource(v=vs.100).aspx
This is a common problem in VB code since VB is not very strict about interpreting object types - it allows more variation in allowing one object type being used in place of another (especially with Option Strict Off).